# Eclipse RCP and Iterate through Perspectives and Views

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP application with many plug-ins. Each plug-in have its own perspective with new views or shared views.
I need to create a separate application based on the original one with the plug-ins.
This application will act as a permissions configurator for each plug-in/perspective.

To do that I need to do the following:

- force initialization of all plug-in at start up
- get all perspective objects in the application and display the IDs
- for each perspective get all views associated to the perspective and display its IDs
- for each view object get all properties (each view in fact will inherit from a special base one : SpecialView for example)

Based on that one special role (Administator) will configure permissions for all other roles (which perspective should be displayed, in each perspective which views will be displayed, on each view which commands will be active, etc).

I have to questions regarding to the above requirements:

- How to force initialization on all plug-ins at startup (Eclipse use lazy activation)?
- How to get perspective objects (not `IPerspectiveDescriptor`) and view objects?

Answer (score 0):

To force the activation you can set a flag in the `plugin.xml` editor, provided that the plugin is a Singleton.

To find the views and the perspectives you could cycle the extension registry, providing the correct id's of the plug-ins and the view and perspective extension points:

```
IExtensionRegistry er = Platform.getExtensionRegistry();
IExtensionPoint ep = er.getExtensionPoint(plug-in_id, extensionId);
IExtensions[] ext = ep.getExtensions();
```

Once you have the extensions you can have also the class implementing it and so on.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. I've tried, but it looks like ep (IExtensionPoint) from your example contains  only Eclipse extensions. And I've use debugger after I've activated all plug-ins.

Comment: If you want to find the views you have to cycle through the extensions of the "org.eclipse.ui.view" extension point, i.e IExtensionPoint ep = er.getExtensionPoint("org.eclipse.ui.views"); ep.getExtensions(); In this array you find the config parameters of all the view in the RCP. In my Insatnce I found: com.collabnet.subversion.merge[15]

com.instantiations.designer.core[29]

org.deved.antlride.debug.ui[121]

org.deved.antlride.ui[129] and not only org.eclipse.* views

Comment: Hi. Thank you again. I will try your solution. I need first to get perspective objects, form that I can access views objects (I already done that).

Comment: Ok, I've ran your example. The problem is that I've got extensions (views) ID's, not actual objects of the views. I miss something ?

Comment: this: PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findVie
w(viewID); i forgot to post :)

Comment: Hi. Thank you. With your solution I can access the view objects. The only problem is that I need perspective objects and I need them to be created already.   But I have found a solution : I got access to a WorkbenchPage object. For this object via reflection I've forced to create perspectives via private method : createPerspective() and get them back with getOpenInternalPerspectives() private method.  Anyway , thank you again for your time and patience. Florin P

Comment: About this solution approach: Iterating the extension point only gives you the default configuration of the perspectives. The user could have opened and closed views in the perspectives.